# Stopping a Robot Through Friction?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

So right now I'm trying to set up the friction of the ground plane (relevant parameters are mu and mu2) so that a 4-wheeled robot (SDF format, no friction mu values set for any links) will come to a stop after rolling down a slope. The software I'm using is Gazebo 2.22 along with ROS Indigo. I'm using the default version of the ground plane as below, with different values of mu and mu2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.5">
  <model name="ground_plane">
    <static>true</static>
    <link name="link">
      <collision name="collision">
        <geometry>
          <plane>
            <normal>0 0 1</normal>
            <size>100 100</size>
          </plane>
        </geometry>
        <surface>
          <friction>
            <ode>
              <mu>100</mu>
              <mu2>50</mu2>
            </ode>
          </friction>
        </surface>
      </collision>
      <visual name="visual">
        <cast_shadows>false</cast_shadows>
        <geometry>
          <plane>
            <normal>0 0 1</normal>
            <size>100 100</size>
          </plane>
        </geometry>
        <material>
          <script>
            <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
            <name>Gazebo/Grey</name>
          </script>
        </material>
      </visual>
    </link>
  </model>
</sdf>
```

Now, there were no problems with the robot actually going down the hill, but I did notice that even with the ground plane's mu and mu2 set to maximum (100, 100), the model went at a (slow) constant velocity with no signs of stopping after coming down the hill. I'm trying to avoid setting the mu and mu2 values for the model itself, but are there other parameters that I need to adjust so the robot can actually come to a stop after rolling down the hill? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6627/stopping-a-robot-through-friction?/) by [K. Zeng](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/835/k.-zeng/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 103 on 2014-07-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zheng yo chen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/800/zheng-yo-chen/) on 2014-07-17**:
I have the same problem.My robot alway slides on the ground,even if I set friction up to 1000.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You will need the wheel slip plugin enabled to avoid slipping down the hill when the robot is stationary.

The plugin: https://github.com/osrf/gazebo/blob/gazebo11/plugins/WheelSlipPlugin.hh

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2020-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0